# DIV with text truncated

Tags: css

I'm tryng to make a div responsive to tablet view.

Here are some picture to explain what is my problem:

[div (Desktop view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDDT1.jpg)

[div (Tablet view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7unj.jpg)

Div 2a, 2b & 2c contains text which must be truncate in tablet view (text in the same line).

Thanks in advance for you answers.

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: Depends on how your CSS and HTML looks like but I would say. Do not set a fixed height for div 2a, 2b and 2c and work with percentages. Look at this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kw8vgzy9/)

Comment: Please add photos (screenshots) to question.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.container {
    background: red;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}

.div1, .div2 {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 30px;
}

.div1 {
    background: blue;
    width: 60px;
}

.div2 {
    background: orange; 
}

.div2a, .div2b {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="div1">
            <!--<img src="some-image.png" />-->
        </div>
        <div class="div2">
            <div class="div2a">Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum dolla Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum dollar</div>
            <div class="div2b">Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum dolla Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum dollar</div>
            <div class="div2c">Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum dolla Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum dollar</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My situation is more complex than the expected. Here is my website with the messy div in header (centerright side): goo.gl/LwFD5a